# Android Support Toolbar shadow API > 19

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar

Using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, I find that it displays a weird shadow in devices with API > 19.

How it looks in **Android 4.4.2 API 19**:

[image]

How it looks in anything with **API >19**:

[image]

**I'd need it to look like it does with API 19**, where it does not have any shadows and rather "integrates" with the background.

---

Since I'm using this Activity with a DrawerLayout, I have 2 layouts.

activity_main_tabbed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_tabbed_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="right">

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_main_tabbed_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_main_tabbed_content.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/activity_background_vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btn_toolbar_back"
                android:src="@drawable/left_white_arrow"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btn_back_toolbar_margin_right"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/btn_back_toolbar_height"
                android:minWidth="@dimen/btn_back_toolbar_width"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
            <rokk3rlabs.dingding.utils.views.FontTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_text_size"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <!--   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/activity_background</item>-->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

styles.xml (v21)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/statusBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make the AppBarLayout have a solid background or set its `app:elevation="0dp"` (*not* `android:elevation`).

Note: Why do you set every color to colorPrimary is puzzling. Purple text over purple background is not going to work. It also makes it impossible to know where the appbar layout ends and the activity background begins in the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the response. "It also makes it impossible to know where the appbar layout ends and the activity background begins in the screenshot" is actually what the client wants!

Comment: In that case I'd suggest just 
        `<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>` and maybe even `android:colorBackground` for popups. White text by default should be fine.

Comment: Setting app:elevation="0dp" for AppBarLayout worked. Thanks!